# Why doesn't work if I change variables global, before the function?

Tags: php, function, variables, scope, global

The next PHP code makes the names initial letter upper case, the others lower case:

```
<?php
$a1 = "WILLIAM";
$a2 = "henry";
$a3 = "gatES";
fix_names();
echo $a1 . " " . $a2 . " " . $a3;
function fix_names()
{
 global $a1;
 global $a2;
 global $a3;
 $a1 = ucfirst(strtolower($a1));
 $a2 = ucfirst(strtolower($a2));
 $a3 = ucfirst(strtolower($a3));
}
/*Output: William Henry Gates*/
?>
```

If I change variables scope to global out of the function it doesnt work:

```
<?php
$a1 = "WILLIAM";
$a2 = "henry";
$a3 = "gatES";
global $a1;
global $a2;
global $a3;
fix_names();
echo $a1 . " " . $a2 . " " . $a3;
function fix_names()
{
$a1 = ucfirst(strtolower($a1));
$a2 = ucfirst(strtolower($a2));
$a3 = ucfirst(strtolower($a3));
}
/*Output: WILLIAM henry gatES*/
?>
```

Please explain me why it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope. For example:

```
<?php
    $a = 1; /* global scope */ 

    function test()
    { 
        echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
    } 

    test();
?>
```

> **This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the `$a` variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope.** You may notice that this is a little bit different from the C language in that global variables in C are automatically available to functions unless specifically overridden by a local definition. This can cause some problems in that people may inadvertently change a global variable.
>
> **In PHP global variables must be declared global inside a function if they are going to be used in that function.**

reference: [http://php.net/variables.scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

So in order to get access to variables from outside the function you need to declare them `global` *inside* the function, otherwise you are trying to do a `ucfirst(strtolower($a1))` on a variable `$a1` that doesn't even exist in the current (local) scope.